# Can I start a parallel process from while loop in python?

Tags: python

I need to start another process to run parallel with the while loop:

```
while True:
    #bunch of stuff happening
    if #something happens:
        #do something (here I have something that takes time and while loop will 'pause' untill this 
                       finishes. I need the while loop to somehow continue looping parallel with 
                       this process.)
```

I tried something like this:

```
while True:
    #bunch of stuff happening
    if #something happens:
        exec(open("filename.py").read()) #here I tried to call for another script but the while loop 
                                          won't continue. It just runs this script and finishes, but 
                                          I need this secont script to run parallel with the while loop looping.
```

Comment: Check python's `multiprocessing` module

Comment: Do you really need a parallel *process*, or would a separate *thread* be enough?

Comment: I basically need something that can run simultaneously. I need the while loop to continue looping while the process in the if condition is executing. Hope you understand my english.

Comment: What you are looking for is called 'concurrency' and python (like most languages) has some build ins to handle it. As @MohitC suggested, check out [Multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), especially the subprocess or the Threading module. If it is more complex, [AsyncIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) may be your best bet

Answer (score 2):

You could use `multiprocessing` for this. Check the doc [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)

Here's a minimalistic example, hope this helps you.

```py
import multiprocessing
number_of_processes = 5

def exec_process(filename):
    #your exec code goes here

p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = number_of_processes)

while True:
    if: #something happens
        p.apply_async(exec_process, (filename,))
p.close()
p.join()
```

Additionally, it is also good to use `callback` which becomes like master to your processes where you could define your terminating conditions.

Your definition could be like:

```py
def exec_process(filename):
    try:
        #do what it does
        return True
    except:
        return False

def callback(result):
    if not result:
        #do what you want to do in case of failure
        #something like p.terminate()
        #indicate failure to global variables

#Now apply call becomes:
p.apply_async(exec_process, (filename,), callback=callback)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use asyncio to do that. Here's a fully working example of a basic producer/consumer:

```
import asyncio
import random
from datetime import datetime
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Measurement(BaseModel):
    data: float
    time: datetime


async def measure(queue: asyncio.Queue):
    while True:
        # Replicate blocking call to recieve data
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("Measurement complete!")
        for i in range(3):
            data = Measurement(
                data=random.random(),
                time=datetime.utcnow()
            )
            await queue.put(data)

    await queue.put(None)


async def process(queue: asyncio.Queue):
    while True:
        data = await queue.get()
        print(f"Got measurement! {data}")
        # Replicate pause for http request
        await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
        print("Sent data to server")


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
queue = asyncio.Queue(loop=loop)
meansurement = measure(queue)
processor = process(queue)
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(processor, meansurement))
loop.close()
```

Comment: @Selman Have you tried this approach? I can't continue to help without feedback